# Issue calling function inside function - StencilJS

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

Am following a tutorial (building drag and drop file uploader), am using StencilJS (for the practice/fun) and have run into an error.

This is some of the code, I can post all of it if need be.

```
@Component({
  tag: 'dynamic-uploader',
  styleUrl: 'dynamic-uploader.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class DynamicUploader {
  @Element() public dynamicUploader: HTMLElement;
  @State() dropzoneActive: boolean = false;
  @State() stagedFiles: Array<StagedFile> = [];

  componentDidLoad() {
    ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
      this.dynamicUploader.addEventListener(eventName, this.handleDefaultPrevention, false);
      document.body.addEventListener(eventName, this.handleDefaultPrevention, false);
    });

    ['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
      this.dynamicUploader.addEventListener(eventName, () => (this.dropzoneActive = true), false);
    });

    ['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
      this.dynamicUploader.addEventListener(eventName, () => (this.dropzoneActive = false), false);
    });

    this.dynamicUploader.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDroppedFile, false);
  }

  handleDefaultPrevention(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

  handleFiles(file)  {
    //   files = [...files];
    //   files.forEach(this.handleFilePreview);
  }

  // handleFiles = files => {
  //   files = [...files];
  //   files.forEach(this.handleFilePreview);
  // };

  handleDroppedFile(event: InputEvent) {
    let dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    let files = dataTransfer.files;
    console.log(this.dynamicUploader);

    Array.from(files).forEach(i => this.handleFilePreview(i));
  }

  handleFilePreview(file: File) {
    this.stagedFiles = [...this.stagedFiles, <staged-file file={file}></staged-file>];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        {`The dropzone is ${this.dropzoneActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}
        <form id="dynamic-uploader" class={{ 'is-active': this.dropzoneActive }}>
          <p>Upload Evidence</p>
          <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple accept="image/*" />
          <label class="button" htmlFor="file-input">
            Select some files
          </label>
        </form>
        <div class="stage-files">{this.stagedFiles}</div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

Essentially it seems that the handleFiles method doesn't work (when I debug) the function doesn't exist if I write it as an arrow function, which I did because I thought that there were issues with scope. But writing it the standard way doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you missing the `class` keyword? If not, can you add how your class looks?

Comment: @Kokodoko have updated it now

Comment: But now `this.handleFiles()` isn't called anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You've not called the handleFile in the code that's why the typescript compiler removes it as part of the code optimizations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).